# Payment status field is not dynamically updated in Magento 2.4.6-P4

Tags: magento2

[image: Magento 2.4.6-P4, the checkout/#paymen not update dinamic]

I'm working on my eCommerce website built with Magento 2.4.6-p4 and I encountered a strange issue during the checkout process. The 'State' field doesn't update dynamically after selecting a 'Country'. Instead, it requires using the newly added 'Update' button to manually refresh the State value. Previously, this worked flawlessly without requiring any manual intervention.

I have tried reverting recent changes and uninstalling new modules but the problem still exists. Could someone guide me on how to solve this issue and restore automatic updating functionality for the 'State' field within the checkout?

Thank you very much in advance for your valuable time and assistance. Here is more relevant information below: